# Trap SIGINT not working in Alpine Linux ash shell

Tags: linux, shell, alpine-linux, ash

I have a limited rights user in Alpine Linux whose login shell has been changed to a script in `/etc/passwd/` as follows:

```
user:x:1001:1001:Linux User,,,:/home/user:/home/user/menu.sh
```

Inside the script, I want to trap INT so that the user can only exit using the relevant menu option but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should display the menu again.

```
#!/bin/ash

# ...
display_menu() {
  # ...
}

trap 'display_menu' INT QUIT TSTP

while true; do
   display_menu
   # ...
done
```

The script runs as it should, but does not trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. Instead, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills the script and brings up the login prompt. If I add just `trap` inside my `display_menu` function, I can see that trap is set because `trap -- 'display_menu' INT` is displayed.

It is worth mentioning that the script handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> okay (it does not go to background). I am using Alpine Linux in a VM not in Docker.

Comment: I can't repro interactively at least; running your script at the root prompt, it runs just as you wanted it to.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I have noticed that the script runs as I want when running it from the root shell (i.e. as user root). However, I want to use it for a limited privilege user and it doesn't work there. Instead Ctrl+C terminates the script and goes to the login prompt. I have tried using ```which``` command to find trap but it does not appear to be a binary, rather it is a built-in command of the shell I think.

Comment: Absolutely; there is no way `trap` could be an external command.